# How to define resource type of validation attribute just once per assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Currently I'm setting up my domain model to use DataAnnotation validation attributes, like the RequiredAttribute and RangeAttribute.

For one property it looks like this:

```
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ModelValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "SurnameRequiredMessage")]
  public string Surname { get; set; }
```

However this isn't the only property, let alone the only model class. The validation messages, however, are only listed only in the ErrorMessageResourceType resource class for the entire assembly.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to define the ErrorMessageResourceType property for an entire class?
- Is it possible to define the ErrorMessageResourceType property for an entire assembly?
- If not, any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom `DataAnnotationsModelValidator`:

```
public class GlobalResourceTypeResourceDataAnnotationsModelValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<ValidationAttribute>
{
    public GlobalResourceTypeResourceDataAnnotationsModelValidator(
        ModelMetadata metadata, 
        ControllerContext context, 
        ValidationAttribute attribute
    )
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        if (Attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType == null)
        {
            Attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ModelValidationMessages);
        }
    }
}
```

and then in Application_Start you need to register an adapter for each attribute you use:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredAttribute), typeof(GlobalResourceTypeResourceDataAnnotationsModelValidator));
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), typeof(GlobalResourceTypeResourceDataAnnotationsModelValidator));
...
```

Comment: Great solution, didn't know it's existance. One additional question; is this solution also possible somehow for WPF applications? Thanks!

Comment: now set the resource type, but how do I know the message key for all resource files? like "can't be empty", "must be a number"